# Saved images are sometimes completely black

Tags: php, image, save

For a website I'm saving product images from links, which usually works fine. However some of the pictures that are saved are completely black, while most others coming from the same source are fine. They have all .jpg extension and I don't understand the difference between images that are fine and images that are all black.

Code I'm using to save the image:

```
$source = "http://blablasomething";
$destination = "/somefolder/images";

$imagesize = getimagesize($source);
$orgwidth = $imagesize[0];
$orgheight = $imagesize[1];
$ratio = $orgwidth / $orgheight;

if ($orgwidth > 420) 
{
  $newwidth = 420;
  $newheight = $nw / $ratio;
}
else 
{
  $newwidth = $orgwidth;
  $newheight = $orgheight;
}

$imghandle = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);
$newimage = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth,$newheight);

imagecopyresampled($newimage,$imghandle,0,0,0,0,$newwidth,$newheight,$orgwidth,$orgheight);     
imagejpeg($newimage,$destination,75);

imagedestroy($newimage);
imagedestroy($imghandle);
```

I read so much about similar problems and tried so many solutions, but I wasn't able to solve it. Hopefully anyone here might have a clue.

Comment: Maybe better rely on Imagick?

Comment: Didn't know Imagick, but I will have a look, thanks.

Comment: Does Imagick have to be installed on the server? Because I don't have a dedicated server unfortunately. Can't I just include the php class?

Comment: Oh yes. Any PHP image processing must be installed on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Using Imagick now and the images that were black are now all good. Thanks for the suggestion!